# Composite with render farm

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, denoise

I am looking to render my project on sheep it render farm and then use the ai Denoise node, to clear up noise.
I am not sure if it is possible to use the denoiser node in the compositor because sheep it outputs png.

For me to turn up the samples would take unrealistically long, even on the render farm. And to render and denoise on my own computer is also unpractical. If anyone has a solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Suggest to test one frame, who knows. Also recommend using another farm if png is the only option (for many other reasons...)